# Absolute and relative imports not working for custom package

Tags: python, import, package, python-3.8

I have a package (or what I think should be a package) with a directory structure:

```
Switch/
    tests/
        testing.py
    Sw.py
    #otherfiles
```

I am trying to import Sw.py from testing.py. I have tried several things, including `from .. import Sw`, `import ..Sw`, `from Switch import Sw` and several other variations. I have tried these with and without and `__init__.py` file in the Switch directory and in the tests directory. The primary error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/testing.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .. import Sw
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Though I also get syntax errors when I try `import ..Sw` and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Switch'` when I try `from Switch import Sw`.

I have done my best to ensure none of the directories in the package are in the path or pythonpath, though I am on WSL running Python installed on Windows, so the paths are somewhat complex.

When I go to the directory above Switch and run `python -c "import Switch.Sw"` it works correctly, but inside the Switch directory it responds with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Switch'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem was that I was running the file as a script or my command as a script. `python -c "import Sw"` treats `"import Sw"` as a script which is why relative and absolute imports weren't working. It wasn't treating Sw as part of a package, just a standalone module. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) cleared things up for me. I should have been doing `python -m Switch.Sw`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to go up a directory and then you should be able to import from your package

```py
import os, sys
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent_dir_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_path, os.pardir))
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir_path)
```

I know it's cumbersome but I'm not sure if there's a better solution.